# Vagrant on Windows and access to shared folders

Tags: windows, networking, vagrant, samba, vagrantfile

I'm working with Vagrant to leverage development environments for my developer teams. Their host OS is Windows, the Vagrant development box is Ubuntu. But most important, our boxes will be stored on our NAS, in folder shared with samba.

My own PC runs Fedora, and my Vagrant file contains this code:

```
config.vm.box_url = "smb://<nas>/boxes/ubuntu-1404-64.box"
```

From Fedora, this works. From Windows, this doesn't with the following error:

> protocol smb not supported or disabled in libcurl

I've tried on Windows with file://, but this logically doesn't work. So, here I am, looking for a good solution. I know a possible workaround is to mount the network share on each Windows PC, but I don't like this solution.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: can you download the box manually? `vagrant box add my-box file:///z:/path/to/boxes/ubuntu-1404-64.box`

Comment: Didn't tested, but I don't see why it won't work. But this implies the user to connect the network share to Z:, and I'd prefer not. But if I don't find a better solution, that would be the definitive solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the status now, but [in the past](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3279) you could've done it by using `file:////server/path/file`, not sure if its still possible.

P.S #1 
`box_url` setting can be an array of possible URLs. So try just putting all possible combination for every OS there to create multiplatform Vagrantfile.

P.S #2
We solved this by hosting the box over local httpd and not using NFS/SMB.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I suspect there are some curl updates which turn things in a different way as even my smb:// format doesn't work anymore on my Fedora. file:////nas... works ony Windows, but not on Fedora, so I've to look at your P.S#1. Thanks.